# Is it possible to remove matches manually in grep mode?

Tags: grep

After running `(grep)` the grep buffer appears with matches. Some of the matches are not relevant, and it would be good to remove them manually. This way I can use the grep buffer to hold only those matches which are relevant to the current investigation.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Absolutely.* And it is extremely *useful* to do that. **`M-x flush-lines`** and **`M-x keep-lines`** are your friends, as well as just `C-k` etc.

(The first thing you need to do is of course `C-x C-q`, to make the buffer writable.)

---

If you use library [Grep+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GrepPlus#Grep%2b) ([`grep+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/grep%2b.el)) then you have these commands, which remove comment lines and toggle such removal:
`grepp-remove-comments`, `grepp-toggle-comments`, which are bound in  grep buffers to **`;`** and **`M-;`**, respectively.

(Grep+ also gives you commands that make it easy to have multiple grep buffers: **`+`** (`grepp-new-buffer`), **`b`** (`grepp-choose-buffer`), and **`r`** (`grepp-rename-buffer-to-last`).)

---

There are also other buffers that are read-only by default and which it can sometimes be useful to use `C-x C-q` and then edit them, in particular (IMHO), `*Messages*`, `*Help*`, and `*Colors*` (from `M-x list-colors-display`). Info *used* to even have a command that lets you edit the current node.

Unfortunately (IMHO), Emacs has generally moved away from such use, making it harder. For example, `*Help*` and `*Messages*` buffers now defined keys in their respective modes, which means that to edit them normally you need to either (1) change to another mode or (2) use `C-q` to be able to insert certain characters.

Comment: I will go so far as to say this answer has changed my life.

Comment: ;-)  ............

Answer (score 0):

If you are an evil user, you can have a binding like `zww 'read-only-mode`, that toggle `read-only-map`. Disable `read-only-mode` and then use `evil-delete` line (i.e. `dd`). Of course this does not automatically remove all the lines like `flush-lines`, however, if you want remove a whole region without using complex regular expressions, then this is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

[winnow.el](https://github.com/dgtized/winnow.el) provides a handy little minor mode designed for this very purpose, intended for use in `compilation-mode` buffers (or derivatives, which includes `grep-mode`).

It enables key bindings equivalent to `flush-lines` and `keep-lines`, and takes care of the read-only-ness of the text for you.

```
Key   Function
x     winnow-exclude-lines
m     winnow-match-lines
```