# Is there a way to narrow down grep results?

Tags: grep

When I search with `grep`, I get the results like:

> -*- mode: grep; default-directory: "~/code/" -*- Grep started at Wed Feb 24 12:40:28
>
> find . -type d ...

that is followed by multiple lines with results.

Now when I have the result, how do I narrow the search to the relevant results?

One way would be limiting the results to certain files in the folders listed.

Another option would be narrowing it down to a more refined search. For example, I grep for 'select' then how do I narrow down the results to 'select_email'?

Comment: What commend do you use in Emacs?

Comment: I use vc-git-grep

Comment: You can simply do `M-x occur` in `*grep*` buffer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to remove matches manually in grep mode?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34487/is-it-possible-to-remove-matches-manually-in-grep-mode)

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Dziekuje very much! It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Arkadiusz Drabczyk has suggested in his comment,

> M-x occur

is the best answer for my needs. Thank you very much!

Comment: You can accept your own answer.